# How to submit a pyFlink job to remote Kubernetes session cluster?

Tags: python, kubernetes, apache-flink, pyflink

Currently, I have a running Flink Kubernetes session cluster (Flink version 1.13.2) and I can access the web UI by `port-forward` also, I can submit the WordCount jar example by this command `./bin/flink run -m localhost:8081 examples/batch/WordCount.jar` from my local environment.

But when I try to submit the pyFlink example by command `./bin/flink run -m localhost:8081 -py examples/python/table/batch/word_count.py` the job freezes and the log says that is waiting for the results.

I tried many ways including creating virtualenv, passing pyClientExecutable and pyexec, syncing local and remote python versions but, none of them worked.

What am I missing? How can I submit python example to the remote session cluster?

***Note***: when I submit pyFlink word_count example in the job manager pod, it runs without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any Flink-1.13 on hand; however, the same example in Flink-1.15 has a line of comment to remind you to remove the `.wait`.